# Error while changing the flutter theme color to black

Tags: flutter, material-design

My first steps in Flutter on Android Studio. My steps:

1. Download and install Android Studio
2. Download and install Flutter and Dart
3. Creating the first default app in flutter

This is the demo app:

[image]

In the commentary in the code of this app we have:

> ```
>     // This is the theme of your application.
>     // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
>     // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
>     // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
>     // "hot reload"
> ```

I changed `Colors.blue` to `Colors.green` and the Hot Reload works fine the app changes to green. But when I try to change to `Colors.black` I have the error:

> type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'.

The full code of the demo app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: new Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug paint" (press "p" in the console where you ran
          // "flutter run", or select "Toggle Debug Paint" from the Flutter tool
          // window in IntelliJ) to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also paste code here?

Comment: code added to the post

Comment: try black54 and let me know. like Colors.black54 or black54

Comment: Color.black54 is the same as Color.black

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can't use `Colors.black` because it is not a `MaterialColor` and `primarySwatch` expects a material color palette.

If you go to the definition of `ThemeData` you will see the following:

```
  ///  * The primary color palette (the [primarySwatch]), chosen from
  ///    one of the swatches defined by the material design spec. This
  ///    should be one of the maps from the [Colors] class that do not
  ///    have "accent" in their name.
```

For instance, the definition of `Colors.blue` is:

```
  static const MaterialColor blue = MaterialColor(
    _bluePrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFE3F2FD),
      100: Color(0xFFBBDEFB),
      200: Color(0xFF90CAF9),
      300: Color(0xFF64B5F6),
      400: Color(0xFF42A5F5),
      500: Color(_bluePrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
      700: Color(0xFF1976D2),
      800: Color(0xFF1565C0),
      900: Color(0xFF0D47A1),
    },
  );
  static const int _bluePrimaryValue = 0xFF2196F3;
```

While the definition of Colors.black is:

```
static const Color black = Color(0xFF000000);
```

That is why you can't use black there. For the same reason you can't use `Colors.white`. Those two are the exceptions to the above explanation of using colors that doesn't have the accent word.

If you want black, you can create your own palette:

```
const MaterialColor primaryBlack = MaterialColor(
  _blackPrimaryValue,
  <int, Color>{
    50: Color(0xFF000000),
    100: Color(0xFF000000),
    200: Color(0xFF000000),
    300: Color(0xFF000000),
    400: Color(0xFF000000),
    500: Color(_blackPrimaryValue),
    600: Color(0xFF000000),
    700: Color(0xFF000000),
    800: Color(0xFF000000),
    900: Color(0xFF000000),
  },
);
const int _blackPrimaryValue = 0xFF000000;
```

And then use the `primaryBlack` instead of Colors.black.

You could adjust the different colors in the palette.

Comment: Is there a way to have a black theme?

Comment: Yes you can, using your own palette. I have edited the answer.

Comment: 1) Created a "colors.dart" file in "lib" folder with `import 'package:flutter/material.dart` and copy/paste your code 2) in "main.dart" changed from `Colors.black` to `primaryBlack` 3) in "main.dart" file added `import 'colors.dart'`;  and works thx!

Answer (score 19):

Also you cold simply use

```dart
theme: ThemeData.dark()
```

to change your applications theme to Dark

Answer (score 7):

I have used following code to get `Black Color` theme.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        //primarySwatch: Colors.black,

      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter First Home Page' ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Color Code:**

[image]

**Inside Theme Data: (theme_data.dart)**

```
........
......

brightness ??= Brightness.light;
final bool isDark = brightness == Brightness.dark;
primarySwatch ??= Colors.blue;
primaryColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[900] : primarySwatch;
primaryColorBrightness ??= estimateBrightnessForColor(primaryColor);
primaryColorLight ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[500] : primarySwatch[100];
primaryColorDark ??= isDark ? Colors.black : primarySwatch[700];
final bool primaryIsDark = primaryColorBrightness == Brightness.dark;
toggleableActiveColor ??= isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200] : (accentColor ?? primarySwatch[600]);
accentColor ??= isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200] : primarySwatch[500];
accentColorBrightness ??= estimateBrightnessForColor(accentColor);
final bool accentIsDark = accentColorBrightness == Brightness.dark;
canvasColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[850] : Colors.grey[50];
scaffoldBackgroundColor ??= canvasColor;
bottomAppBarColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[800] : Colors.white;
cardColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[800] : Colors.white;
dividerColor ??= isDark ? const Color(0x1FFFFFFF) : const Color(0x1F000000);
.....
.......
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Simple solution. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Why this doesn't work for me? Even after Hot Restart. **Flutter** - `3.0.4`, `android-x64 emulator`

Answer (score 7):

Just use `primaryColor: Colors.black`

I am not getting this whole primarySwatch cr#^...

Answer (score 4):

This is how I fixed it

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static Map<int, Color> color = {
    50: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .1),
    100: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .2),
    200: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .3),
    300: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .4),
    400: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .5),
    500: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .6),
    600: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .7),
    700: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .8),
    800: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .9),
    900: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, 1),
  };
  MaterialColor primeColor = MaterialColor(0xFF337C36, color);
  MaterialColor accentColor = MaterialColor(0xFF337C36, color);
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: primeColor,
        accentColor: accentColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry for that, but I feel the answer of @chemamolins answer should not be the accepted one.
And perhaps it's necessary to clarify some key points about colors, cause misunderstanding of these concepts can lead to bad design.

**About Colors:**

The fact of the matter is that black and white are not colors.
See: https://adobe.com/creativecloud/design/discover/is-black-a-color.html

Physically, when your eyes see some white it's because the surface reflect an addition of all the colors of the spectrum.
And so you can't say white is "a color" cause it's "some colors".

On the other hand black is just what you see when no colors have been reflected.
And "no colors" means... "no colors" right ?

**Back to Flutter:**

> The value of this color should the same the value of index 500 and shade500.

See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html

And so, for all the value above 500 (600...900) nothing exists because nothing can be darker than black.
That's why it's a non-sense to create a swatch for something like that.

**The right Solution:**

To my eyes, the cleaner solution has been proposed by @MacDonal_11

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      //primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      primaryColor: Colors.black,
      
      /**
       * ... [The rest of your config here] ...
       */
      
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    ),
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
  );
}
```

Comment: Why this doesn't work for me? Even after Hot Restart. **Flutter** - `3.0.4`, `android-x64 emulator`

Comment: This post is from two years ago, and I haven't played with Flutter since then. Perhaps the best thing for you would be to create a new question on StackOverflow. There are certainly people much more competent than me to answer your question as of today.

Comment: Thanks. And also, I found, as for me, a better solution - to create a custom theme)

Comment: Feel free to share your up to date solution, it could help someone else ;p

Answer (score 1):

```
theme: ThemeData(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.purple,
          secondary: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),
  ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This is a cool solution!