# Colors.black doesn't work but Colors.blue does - flutter

Tags: flutter

I was wondering why some Colors. don't work on flutter?
For example, I can use Colors.blue for my primarySwatch in the theme for my MaterialApp.
However, Colors.black and some others return a red squiggly line under but doesn't say what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS code you might not getting error message. I'm using Android Studio and it complains that

```
The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialColor?'
```

Since **primarySwatch** accepts **MaterialColor** you cannot use Colors.black since it is not MaterialColor type but type of Color:

```
static const MaterialColor blue = MaterialColor(
    _bluePrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFE3F2FD),
      100: Color(0xFFBBDEFB),
      200: Color(0xFF90CAF9),
      300: Color(0xFF64B5F6),
      400: Color(0xFF42A5F5),
      500: Color(_bluePrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
      700: Color(0xFF1976D2),
      800: Color(0xFF1565C0),
      900: Color(0xFF0D47A1),
    },
  );
```

Also I want to note that Colors.blue has palette of colors where Colors.black has only one color.

```
  static const Color black = Color(0xFF000000);
```

Comment: It is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52577730/13357646)