# What is the difference when I assign BW and other color in "PrimarySwatch" - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

- Look, Please explain me what is PrimarySwatch actually.!!!

I started learning the Flutter right from yesterday. When writing a code in flutter I noticed something that is demonstrated from the following images. Please can you help me what is the difference?
[When the value is set to Black or White the IDE underlines those values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdWW8.png)

[But the IDE is completely ok with using other colors!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gyAh.png)

Why B&W are underlined as value of PrimarySwatch? what happened and what is the actual meaning of the PrimarySwatch?

I looked out on YouTube tutorials but didn't got anything!

Comment: maybe you;ve edit the color file, you can try force upgrade to fix issue, `flutter upgrade -f`

Comment: Nope, it just underlines the code but when I run it, it complies completely fine and nothing happens with difference of the value of PrimarySwatch. So, why do we need this thing or what is the difference of these?

Comment: [colorScheme] parameter, or have one generated for them by using the [colorSchemeSeed] and [brightness] parameters. A generated color scheme will be based on the tones of [colorSchemeSeed] and all of its contrasting color will meet accessibility guidelines for readability.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: Okay, so it is related with something like the brightness and other configs of the users and seems to be more complicated. Maybe I should think about that later on after few exp. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `primarySwatch` expects a `MaterialColor` and not `Color`. Both are different in the sense that `MaterialColor` is a color with multiple shades while `Color` is a simple color object. If you look into the definitions, `Colors.grey` is defined as a more complex parameter with multiple color objects:

```
static const MaterialColor grey = MaterialColor(
    _greyPrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      100: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      200: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
      300: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
      350: Color(0xFFD6D6D6), // only for raised button while pressed in light theme
      400: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
      500: Color(_greyPrimaryValue),
      600: Color(0xFF757575),
      700: Color(0xFF616161),
      800: Color(0xFF424242),
      850: Color(0xFF303030), // only for background color in dark theme
      900: Color(0xFF212121),
    },
  );
```

You can find out more in this thread- [Error while changing the flutter theme color to black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577366/error-while-changing-the-flutter-theme-color-to-black)

Comment: The confusion comes from the naming I guess

Comment: Absolutely. They should have reserved a separate name for white and black. Or they could have made a material palette for BW.

Comment: Yah the naming seems complex but was nothing complex. :)